# how to create values.xml for different screens size (landscape mode)

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am working on an android project where I have create these `values.xml` for portrait mode. But the same doesn't for landscape mode. **I even created all the landscape alternative values folder. But the screen using `values-xhdpi` in portrait mode is not using the same in landscape mode. I am unable to figure out while `values` folder is the device using in landscape mode?**

```
values-hdpi
values-mdpi
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

How can I maintain consistency both in portrait and landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the offical documentation, it explains it well:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

However in short add the `land` qualifier like `values-land-hdpi` or `values-sw720dp-land`. What order the qualifiers should be in is defined in the documentation.

Comment: I have created all the landscape alternative values folder. But the screen using `values-xhdpi` in portrait mode is not using the same in landscape mode. I am unable to figure out while values folder is the device using in landscape mode? @patrick-iv

Comment: I also have the same issue